# Unity - Inject an object to Constructor by calling a Method of a Class

Tags: c#, unity-container, ioc-container

I have the following interface and its implementation

```
public class DummyProxy : IDummyProxy
{
    public string SessionID { get; set; }
    public DummyProxy(string sessionId)
    {
        SessionId = sessionId;
    }
}

public interface IDummyProxy
{
}
```

Then I have another class to get a session id

```
public class DummySession
{
    public string GetSessionId()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.Next(0, 100).ToString();
    }
}
```

Now, in my Unity container, I would like to inject 'session id' to DummyProxy every time the container is trying to resolve IDummyProxy. But this 'session id' must be generated from DummySession class.

```
container.RegisterType<IDummyProxy, DummyProxy>(
    new InjectionConstructor(new DummySession().GetSessionId()));
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best approach for this would be to make use of an [`InjectionFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.injectionfactory(v=pandp.51).aspx), i.e.

```
container.RegisterType<IDummyProxy, DummyProxy>(new InjectionFactory(c => 
{
    var session = c.Resolve<DummySession>() // Ideally this would be IDummySession
    var sessionId = session.GetSessionId();

    return new DummyProxy(sessionId);
}));
```

An `InjectionFactory` allows you to execute additional code when creating the instance.

The `c` is the `IUnityContainer` being used to perform the resolve, we use this to resolve the session and then obtain the session id, from that you can then create your `DummyProxy` instance.

Comment: Nice.. this is exactly what I want to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. It's possible. It will only create the Session Id once (which is what I'd assume you'd want to do.)

I would personally rather give the DummyProxy a dependency on the DummySession (or better yet, an abstraction like IDummyProxy) and make it call DummySession.GetSessionID().

Comment: Well, I actually need the SessionId be called every time, so each resolve for DummyProxy will have new SessionId.

Comment: I could modify DummyProxy to depend on IDummySession, but I thought there might be a simpler way to do this..